# Function metadata not getting refreshed after table changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am facing frequent issue while trying to fetch the data from functions which contains the latest data for a given join criteria instead of all historical data. Recently we added new columns to these tables based on business requirement but the functions are not getting updated as per the latest table changes. Is there any way to refresh the function metadata. In case of view we have sp_refreshview, do we have any such in functions as well.

For Ex:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[Value](@Code varchar(15))
returns table
return (
    select top 1 *
    from table with (nolock)
    where Code = @Code order by Date desc
)
```

Now the table has been modified to have a new column. But the function is not reflecting that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the closest you can get is defining the function with `SCHEMABINDING`.

As a note, though:  this will not allow you to modify the definition of the table.  Instead, you'll get an error that it is referenced by another object.

This is described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

The other alternative is to use `sp_refreshsqlmodule`, which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of schema binding but the tables have frequent modifications. sp_refreshsqmodule is the one I am looking forand it really worked. Many Thanks.